# Undefined behavior in for loop - shouldn't the expression separation make this well-defined?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I know this topic has been beaten to death a little on SO, but I'm still a little confused about the situation shown below - and multiple people seemed to agree it was right.

I understand that you cannot modify/use a modified variable more than once without an intervening sequence point without it being undefined behavior.  I thought that within a for loop though, the `i != 0;`, `i < n;` and `i--` were all separate expressions, evaluated at known times, and separated by sequence points (as they are full expressions).

Why would this yield undefined behavior?

[image: forum Image]

taken from forum: http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-48979.html

Comment: `for (i != 0;` doesn't make any sense. You check whether `i` is not equal to zero, and then you throw away the result. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I don't know, it's not my code :p.  I was just interested in what made it undefined - and I guess that's the signed/unsigned issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the original code of the post

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i--)
```

the code is undefined because of the way signed integer arithmetic works. There is no guarantee that `i` will ever wrap around and become positive. With unsigned arithmetic, the code becomes defined (*but the behavior is unspecified, because the size of an `unsigned int` is unspecified*).

As for the line corresponding to your screenshot, the variable `i` is never initialized, hence the undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, I guess I over-focused on that line and thought it was something more subtle, haha.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i--)
```

This is code is undefined behavior if `i` is a signed integer AND if the `i--` expression makes `i` overflows. (Actually in the C terminology only signed integers can overflow.)

Comment: can you explain why a postfix decrement on integer makes it overflow?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers commented on a different code than the one actually posted. The code was originally a puzzle, and one of the proposed solutions was to write the following:

```
for (i != 0; i < n; i--)
```

The problem with this is that it never assigns an initial value to `i`. Normally, this goes into the first part of the `for`-construct, but here is has been rewritten into (the totally pointless) `i != 0`. (It is pointless as it has no side effects and it's value is not used -- but, hey, this was a puzzle.)

Hence, this can run the loop an arbitrary number of times.